# How do I filter using both AND and OR statements?

Tags: sas

I have a data set, `df`, that looks like this:

```
ZIP    TEENS     ADULTS     SENIORS   TOTAL
054216 .         2000       .         2000
02216  45        105        10        160
01720  0         256        0         256
02113  .         4122       918       5040
02144  782       20         0         1002
```

I would like to exclude any zip codes that are all adults. In addition, I would like to only keep rows where the adult population is greater than 50%. My code, listed below, keeps rows 1 and 3 even though there are no teens or seniors in those communities. Any tips on what's wrong with it would be appreciated.

```
data adult_zips;
    set df;
    where ((adults/total) > 0.50) and
        ((teens is not missing) or (teens ne 0)) and 
        ((seniors is not missing) or (seniors ne 0));
run;
```

Comment: On a sidenote: I hope this data set isn't a table. A table should not redundantly contain the sum of the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused AND and OR:

```
data adult_zips;
    set df;
    where adults / total > 0.50 
      and 
      (
        (teens is not missing and teens ne 0)
        or
        (seniors is not missing and seniors ne 0)
      );
run;
```

Or simpler:

```
data adult_zips;
    set df;
    where adults / total > 0.50 
      and (teens > 0 or seniors > 0);
run;
```

Or even:

```
data adult_zips;
    set df;
    where adults / total > 0.50 
      and adults ne total;
run;
```

Comment: should have seen that. thanks for sharing the other solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

```
data adult_zips;
set df;
where adults / total > 0.50 
  and (teens > 0 or seniors > 0);
```

run;

This is the easiest solution.